# Переменная $quantity не принимает значение 1 при отправке пустого значения?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["quantity"])){
   $_POST["quantity"] = (int)$_POST["quantity"];
   $quantity = $_POST["quantity"];
}
else {
   $quantity = 1;
}

$item_price = 5.99;
printf("%d x item = $%.2f", $quantity, $quantity * $item_price);
?>
<form action="buy.php" method="post">
   <p>Обновить количество:</p>
   <input name="quantity" size="2" value="<?php echo $quantity;?>">
   <input type="submit" value="Изменить количество">
</form>
<?php echo gettype($quantity);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отправленное пустое значение из формы будет восприниматься как null. То есть нужна дополнительная проверка "не равна ли принятая переменная нулю".

```
if (isset($_POST["quantity"]) && $_POST["quantity"] != null){
$quantity = (int)$_POST["quantity"];
}
```

Comment: А ноль как собираетесь принять?

Comment: Заменил $_POST["quantity"] != 0 на $_POST["quantity"] != null

Answer (score 0):

Думаю лучше так

```
if (!empty($_POST["quantity"])){
  $quantity = intval($_POST["quantity"]);
}
else {
  $quantity = 1;
}
```

Comment: Аналогично. Ноль не предусмотрен к вводу?

Comment: @Visman думаю это уже вопрос к автору, я лишь ответил в рамках его кода

Comment: Минус 1 так как empty не проверяет сущетвование ключа массива так что варниг вам  обеспечен, лишние тормоза и ошибки...